# Prolog List Squaring, Modifying element in List

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a short Prolog program which takes a list of numbers and returns a list where all numbers have been squared.

Ie: `[2,4,5]` => `[4,16,25]`

My code so far:

```
list_of_squares([X], L) :-
    L is X^2.
list_of_squares([X|XS], [X^2|M]) :-
    list_of_squares(XS, M).
```

For some reason though Prolog doesn't like me squaring X while adding it to a list... Any thoughts on how I could do this?

Comment: You could just do `list_of_squares(L, S) :- maplist(square, L, S). square(X, XS) :- XS is X^2.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not that far off, but you make two small mistakes:

Firstly, you mix element `X` with list `L`. Your first clause should be:

```
list_of_squares([X], [Y]):-
  Y is X ^ 2.
```

Secondly, you cannot perform an arithmetic function in list notation.
Your second clauses should be as follows:

```
list_of_squares([X|Xs], [Y|Ys]):-
  Y is X ^ 2,
  list_of_squares(Xs, Ys).
```

Thirdly, there is a more fundamental problem. With the first two fixes, your code works, but the base case, i.e. the first clause, is not that well chosen. (A) the code cannot process the empty list. (B) For a singleton list the code is needlessly nondeterministic, because both clauses apply. This is solved by choosing the base case wisely:

```
squares([], []).
squares([X|Xs], [Y|Ys]):-
  Y is X ^ 2,
  squares(Xs, Ys).
```

Comment: As a general question, is there anything inherently wrong with using L instead of Y?

Comment: @DarioP none whatsoever. `Y` and `L` are just variable names. You could also use `Fred`. Or `Dario`. :)

Comment: @DarioP Not at all! Any variable name will do, as long as it is used consistently (e.g. is not identical to another variable that is supposed to represent something else). Purely for didactical purposes, I have chosen variable names `X` and `Y` to stand for a single element, and `Xs` and `Ys` to stand for lists of elements. The reason why I did not copy your use of `L` is that it is sometimes used to denote a list. (Ahh, Lurker you're quick :-P)

Comment: @WouterBeek thanks! I've tried implementing your suggestions, so for list [2,3,4] I get [4,9|16]. Just wondering where the | comes from...

Comment: @DarioP The pipe character is normally used to separate the head of a list from its tail, e.g. `[a|[b,c]] == [a,b,c]`. As far as I know, `[4,9|16]` is not a list, so I'm not sure how you get that result. Which Prolog implementation are you using?

Comment: Hi @WouterBeek sorry ignore that, I was typing Y instead of [Y]. Thanks for your help, works fine now!

Comment: @DarioP: `L` might suggest that there is a list. But its about numbers

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **general** method how you can localize such an error. First, let's start with your exemple:

```
?- list_of_squares([2,4,5],[4,16,25]).
   false.
```

Oh no! It fails! There is a very general method what to do in such a situation:

### Generalize the query

So we replace `[4,16,25]` by a new, fresh (ah, true freshness!) variable:

```
?- list_of_squares([2,4,5],L).
   L = [2^2,4^2|25]
;  false.
```

That's way better: Now you know that there is a "result", but that result it not what you expected.

Next,

### Minimize the query

The list is way too long, so I will chop off some elements. Say, the first two:

```
?- list_of_squares([5],L).
   L = 25
;  false.
```

Again, wrong, but smaller. Now, where is the error for that? To get it

### Specialize your program

```
list_of_squares([X], L) :-
    L is X^2.
list_of_squares([X|XS], [X^2|M]) :- false,
    list_of_squares(XS, M).
```

That program, again gives the same wrong answer! So in there is a bug in the visible part. What we expect is

```
?- list_of_squares([5],[25]).
   false.
```

this to succeed. But where is the error? Again:

### Generalize the query

```
?- list_of_squares([5],[X]).
   false.
```

HET!

Now, you should realize that that rule might be:

```
list_of_squares([X], [Y]):-
  Y is X ^ 2.
```

And the same `(is)/2` should be used in the recursive rule. And, why not accept `[]`.

I, personally, would rather write using [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl):

```
list_of_squares(Xs, Ys) :-
   maplist(\X^XX^(XX is X^2), Xs, Ys).
```

Or, even better, using `library(clpfd)`

```
list_of_squares(Xs, Ys) :-
   maplist(\X^XX^(XX #= X^2), Xs, Ys).
```

Answer (score 0):

Prolog doesn't have a 'functional' mindset, but some standard builtin predicate can help working with lists. In this case

```
list_of_squares(L,S) :- findall(Sq,(member(E,L),Sq is E*E),S).

?- list_of_squares([2,4,5], R).
R = [4, 16, 25].
```

in this case, member/2 play a role similar to lambda expressions, giving a 'name' to each element E available in L. findall/3 compute all solutions of its goal `,(member(E,L),Sq is E*E),`, and collects results (the 'template' expression, that is, `Sq`).